# How can I have two scrollviews in one usercontrol?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I'm trying to have two lists of elements (sales and reservations) in one userconrol. The problem i'm facing is that the content of the scrollviews is overflowing, and not scrollable.

I've tried to change the stackpanels to grid. It does work when using a fixed height in the grid, but I want it to be scalable.

```
<Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="0">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Margin="0 25 0 0" Text="{x:Static properties:Resources.Sales}" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                        <ListView Grid.Row="1" FontSize="18" Height ="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=GridListView}" x:Name="SalesList" ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentOccupancy.Sales}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSale}">

                            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                <behavior:EventToCommandBehavior Command="{Binding SalesViewSelectionChangedCommand}" Event="SelectionChanged" PassArguments="True" />
                            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                            <ListView.View>

                                <GridView>
                                    <GridViewColumn Header="{Binding Source={x:Static properties:Resources.Paid}, StringFormat=is\{0\}}">
                                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <TextBlock x:Name="paid" Text="{Binding Paid}"/>
                                                <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Paid}" Value="0">
                                                        <Setter TargetName="paid" Property="Text" Value="{x:Static properties:Resources.Unpaid}" />
                                                    </DataTrigger>
                                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Paid}" Value="1">
                                                        <Setter TargetName="paid" Property="Text" Value="{x:Static properties:Resources.Paid}" />
                                                    </DataTrigger>
                                                </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    </GridViewColumn>
                                    <GridViewColumn
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Product.Name}"
                            Header="{x:Static properties:Resources.Name}" />
                                    <GridViewColumn
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Product.Price}"
                            Header="{x:Static properties:Resources.Price}" />
                                </GridView>
                            </ListView.View>
                        </ListView>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ScrollViewer>
                <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Margin="0 25 0 0" Grid.Row="2" Text="{x:Static properties:Resources.Reservations}" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                        <ListView Grid.Row="3" FontSize="18" Height ="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=GridListView}" ItemsSource="{Binding FutureReservations}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedReservation}">
                            <ListView.View>
                                <GridView>
                                    <GridViewColumn
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding LastName}"
                            Header="{x:Static properties:Resources.LastName}"/>
                                    <GridViewColumn
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding AmountPeople}"
                            Header="{x:Static properties:Resources.AmountOfPeople}"/>
                                    <GridViewColumn
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding PhoneNumber}"
                            Header="{x:Static properties:Resources.Phone}"/>
                                    <GridViewColumn
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding StartTime, StringFormat=HH:mm dd/MM}"
                            Header="{x:Static properties:Resources.StartTime}"/>
                                </GridView>
                            </ListView.View>
                        </ListView>
                    </StackPanel>

                </ScrollViewer>
            </Grid>
```

I'm trying to have two listviews that both have their own scrollbar, the first listview (sales) must be larger than the second one and the height should not be fixed.

This is what de design should look like:
[Screenshot of designer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2q55a.png)

Comment: Do you really have to scroll the textblock and headers as well as the listview content? The outer scrollviewers are a complication and I personally would prefer a UI design keeps the listview headers in view all the time.

Comment: No, that isn't a requirement at all, I would actually prefer if the header would be non-scrollable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A ListView has a scrollviewer in it.

Putting the listview inside a panel where it doesn't end up with a calculated height will cause problems though.

I suggest you put a grid inside each grid row.

Give it two rows.

Put a textblock in the first and your listview the second.

Here is a simplified version of your markup which illustrates my suggestion.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text="First List"/>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Letters}" Grid.Row="1"/>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text="Second List"/>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Letters}" Grid.Row="1"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

The textblocks and listview headers will remain visible and vertical scrollbars appear for the content of each listview if they do not fit.

Obviously, I have no headers in this version.

[image]